# Add Customer Field and use in own forms in Magento 1.7

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I added new customer fields in module my module update:

```
    $installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$_attributeToAdd = [
    'recordtype'=>[
        'input'=>'select',
        'type'=>'varchar',
        'label'=>Mage::helper('company_partner')->__('String'),
        'visible'=>1,
        'required'=>1,
        'user_defined'=>1,
        'global'=>1,
        'visible_on_front'=>1,
        'source'=>'company_partner/entity_recordtype'

    ],
    'court'=>[
        'input'=>'text',
        'type'=>'varchar',
        'label'=>Mage::helper('company_partner')->__('String),
        'visible'=>1,
        'required'=>0,
        'user_defined'=>1
    ],
    'krs'=>[
        'input'=>'text',
        'type'=>'varchar',
        'label'=>Mage::helper('company_partner')->__('String'),
        'visible'=>1,
        'required'=>0,
        'user_defined'=>1
    ],
    ...other fields
];
    $_order=2200;
    foreach($_attributeToAdd as $_key=>$_value){
        if(isset($setup)){
            unset($setup);

        }
        if(isset($_oAttribute)){
            unset($_oAttribute);
        }
        $setup = Mage::getModel('customer/entity_setup', 'core_setup');

        $_entitytypeId = $setup->getEntityTypeId('customer');
        $_attributeTypeId = $setup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($_entitytypeId);
        $_attributeGroupId = $setup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($_entitytypeId,$_attributeTypeId);

        $setup->addAttribute('customer',$_key,$_value);
        $setup->addAttributeToGroup($_entitytypeId,$_attributeTypeId,$_attributeGroupId,$_key,$_order);

        Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', $_key)->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer','customer_account_create','customer_account_edit','checkout_register','unizeto_partner_account_edit','magestore_affiliateplus_account_edit'))->save();

        $_oAttribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer',$_key);
        $_oAttribute->setData('used_in_forms',['adminhtml_customer']);
        $_oAttribute->save();
        $_order++;
    }

$installer->endSetup();
```

I tryed also in

```
$_oAttribute->setData('used_in_forms',['adminhtml_customer','company_module']);
```

And I see this attributes in admin panel (add/edit customoer) but in my own module I can't use in forms/action controller (can't see filed in admin data).

I don't know why.

My module overwrite form and action controller from other not core magento module.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [This link](http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator)

to create customer attribute.This is safe.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this site create zip with system.xml where are config data fields. I don't know as is related to all tutorials like [this](http://www.magecorner.com/adding-custom-customer-attributes/) where is use code which create new records in database.

Comment: you just need to create extension with using `Need Add Customer Attribute` with yes it will ask for your attribute option.all remain option are set to 'No' so it will only create customer attribute file.